# RxJS filter an observable with value in another Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I am looking for the best RxJs way of filtering an Observable with the value held in another.

Firstly I have an observable containing a ticker which comes from the route Params. Lets say it is "BTC" in ticker$

Then I have a store observable which returns me a list of coins (1414 of them) in fullCoinList$

I want the this.coin$ observable to contain only the items in this.fullCoinList$ observable that contains the string "BTC" somewhere in the ticker name.

FullCoinList$ looks like this.

```
  [{ticker: "ETHBTC", price: "0.04597600"}
   {ticker: "LTCBTC", price: "0.00457100"}
   {ticker: "BNBBTC", price: "0.01008450"}
   {ticker: "NEOBTC", price: "0.00163300"}
   {ticker: "QTUMETH", price: "0.00541200"}
   {ticker: "EOSETH", price: "0.00229400
   .... + 1408more]
```

My NgOnInit looks like this

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe( (params: ParamMap) => {
      this.ticker$ = of(params.get('ticker'))
    })

    this.fullCoinList$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectAllCoins))
    
    this.coins$ = this.fullCoinList$.pipe(
      filter( coin => coin.ticker.includes(this.ticker$)) // this line needs work
    )
  }
```

Is this a good use case for mergeMap, concatMap or something similar? And how would I best implement it? I'm not sure includes is the correct method either.

EDIT: I have added a stackBlitz
[Blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-observable-filter123?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use `combineLatest` to combine both observables and go from there.

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
...
ngOnInit(): void {
    // we can get rid of a subscription here and assign it to the observable directly
    this.ticker$ = this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(
      map(paramMap => paramMap.get('ticker')),
    );

    this.fullCoinList$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectAllCoins))
    
    this.coins$ = combineLatest(this.fullCoinList$, this.ticker$).pipe(
      // the filter is the array filter and not rxjs filter
      map(([fullCoinList, ticker]) => fullCoinList.filter(fullCoin => fullCoin.ticker.includes(ticker))),
    );
  }
```

Something like that should work.

Comment: Thanks. I could not get this to work. I have added a stackBlitz and still I can't seem to get the list to filter correctly.

Comment: Actually my bad. It looks like I just needed to change the ticker$ to UPPERCASE. Thanks